# Disable text file previews/thumbnails in nautilus

Tags: nautilus, thumbnails

Nautilus in 14.04 generates "thumbnails" of all text files in that it shows them all as the same, blank text icon. If I turn off thumbnails altogether, then it displays correct icons, but I need thumbnails of image files. So I tried enabling thumbnails, and then in Dconf disabling them specifically for 'text/css', and so on. This does not work. Can this be achieved without disabling all thumbnails?
I should note I searched this site and there's a few posts here addressing this issue, but those posts are without answers, or referred to other posts - that are also without answers. 
A bit of a vicious circle.
I'd appreciate any suggestions.Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable Text File Preview in Nautilus in Ubuntu 14.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/628899/disable-text-file-preview-in-nautilus-in-ubuntu-14-04)