# Disable Text File Preview in Nautilus in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, nautilus, text, thumbnails, previews

In **Ubuntu 14.04** I find that ***text files*** are displayed with a preview in the icons. I **do not** want to disable preview for all file types because I need thumbnails for images, media and various other files types.

I tried to use dconf editor to disable preview for 'text/plain' mime type. However, it did not work out.

Please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

It's been removed from gtk+ & nautilus starting in 3.14 (15.04) so you'll find it gone in the future if you move up from 14.04
(- I find unfortunate but to each their own..

reference - https://git.gnome.org/browse/nautilus/commit/?h=gnome-3-14&id=67fdde6a9ff2dcbe3ae25fa3e259e77a4951cc46